# How do I upsert into a data warehouse from multiple sources

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-warehouse

I am in the process of building a new data warehouse. On this occasion the warehouse needs to support incremental nightly updates. Pretty standard stuff really.

Previously when building a data warehouse I've either used Created / Updated date columns to drive inserts and updates, or, used the PrimaryKey on the source table and stored that in the warehouse as the natural key and used HashBytes to compare row data.

However on this particular warehouse, the data will be fed from multiple sql tables, which would therefore have multiple primary keys, and / or multiple Created / Updated dates.

What is a typical design pattern for dealing with this situation?

Comment: I'm assuming that in previous implementations you were qualifying source records for migration based on the key or date values resident in the warehouse tables themselves. That may still work if you add a source-tracking mechanism. Have you considered adding a column to act as a FK to an enumeration of the sources that stores the key-or-date basis for migrating from the source?

Comment: Yes, the source primary keys were being stored in the warehouse. Are to suggesting adding multiple source keys into a single column on the warehouse? What about the date columns? Doesn't seem right to have 5 source dates on a fact table.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of storing just the SourceID (or some-such) on the fact table and having a dimension table that describes that source, including what type of inclusion-qualifier (key, date, etc.) it uses as well as the value of that qualifier for the purpose of referencing and updating the ETL processor

Comment: But there are multiple source ids, as maybe as 5. Do you have a visual example of your suggestion?

Comment: You have a fact table that is (I'm assuming) largely de-normalized. There are some columns that reference dimension tables via foreign keys (may or may not be defined as such) so that important data not directly relevant to the "fact" is persisted. I don't see the source of the data as conceptually different from any other dimension